# Operator being surjective

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and fix $g \in L^\infty(X)$. Let $T_g:L^p(X) \rightarrow L^p(X)$ be defined as $T_g(f)=fg$. Prove that $T_g$ is onto if and only if $\frac{1}{g} \in L^\infty(E)$.

One of the directions here is quite simple. If $\frac{1}{g}$ is essentially bounded, then there is $c>0$ such that $c \leq |g(x)|$ for nearly every $x \in X$. If $f' \in L^p(X)$ make $f = \frac{f'}{g}$ which is well defined for nearly every $x \in X$ and we are done. Conversely assume that $T_g$ is surjective, so for every $f' \in L^p(X)$ we can find $f \in L^p(X)$ such that $T_g(f)=fg=f'$. How can I conclude that $\frac{1}{g} \in L^\infty(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: if $\|1/g\|_\infty =\infty $ then $f$ could be arbitrarily large where $g$ is arbitrarily close to zero, so it is enough to show that in this case $f$ cannot belong to $L^p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, do I need to divide by $g$? Is this even allowed, since we do not know whether $g \neq 0$ nearly everywhere?

Comment: Assuming that it is not bounded I get that the set $\{x:|g(x)|<\frac{1}{c}\}$ has positive measure for every $c>0$. But I am not sure how to proceed here, I apologize.

Comment: set $A_n:=\{x: 1/(n+1)<|g(x)|\leqslant 1/n\}$, then if $\|1/g\|_\infty =\infty $ then or $\{x: g(x)=0\}$ have positive measure or there are infinitely many $A_n$ of positive measure. In the latter set $h_1:=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}n\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$ and $h_2:=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(n+1)\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, then $h_1\leqslant |g \mathbf{1}_{C}|\leqslant h_2$ where $C:=\{x:|g(x)|< 1\}$. Now find some appropriate $f'\in L_p$ to show that $f=f'/g\notin L^p$

Comment: sorry, in my previous comment I wanted to mean $|1/g \mathbf{1}_{C}|$ instead of $|g\mathbf{1}_{C}|$